# What or how to test this code with Jasmine ?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, bdd, jasmine2.0

I am quite new with Jasmine tests and I don't know what to test for example in this code --

```
Cemcloud.CRUDEvents = function(onlyEdit) {

if (onlyEdit == undefined) {
    onlyEdit = false;
}
var elements = $('.add, .edit');
if (onlyEdit) {
    elements = $('.edit');
}
elements.on("click", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var ajaxUrl = $(this).data("ajax-url");

    if (ajaxUrl.length > 0) {
        Cemcloud.ajaxConfig = {
            url: ajaxUrl,
            type: 'get',
            context: document.body
        };
        Cemcloud.ajaxCall(Cemcloud.handleAddEditButton);
    }
});
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    Cemcloud.CRUDEvents();
    CustomForm.init();
});
```

If you need anything else like handleAddEditButton or AjaxCall.

Could someone at least write one test so that I could expand this test with more advanced features. I just don't know how or where to start ? 
Something really simple. 
I have installed Jasmine and it runs. I have even install the jasmine example, but I don't get how to implement it in our code.